# Reducing eddy currents, changes the property of the conductor & circuit?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, voltage

In an attempt of reducing the eddy currents in a conductor, such as having gaps to break the induced eddy currents, would that by any chance change the conductor's orientation from series to parallel?

An example, from the following diagrams:
[image]

Imagine both diagrams we're connected to a separate circuit somehow. Diagram(a) is a complete conductor inducing high eddy currents, also a series layout with respect to the circuit. However, if diagram (b) was connect to a circuit, would the conductor be oriented to a parallel circuit? Diving out the input current flow all around the conductor or is it still in series, regardless of the air gaps?

I guess, this goes deeper into my understanding of parallel/series circuit, I would understand that it's usually the components(resistors/diodes/inductors/ etc...) that are connected either in series, or parallel to a circuit. But what about a single individual wire, could it be broken down into the same concept?

Wires usually are in series, one whole piece of conductor, when it brakes into branches that would indicate a parallel circuit being formed, but what about the conductor in diagram(b) then?

A bit, odd comparing a single wire to a whole circuit but I hope the question(s) are clear enough.

Comment: As shown the conductor is still improperly designed for the suppression of eddy currents. The effective loops have been made smaller and they have higher resistance, but they still exist. The correct way would have been to break it up into a fork like structure which does not have any loops, whatsoever.

Comment: True, but is the conductor now considered a sub-parallel circuit? Because of the breaks? When comparing it to a whole conductor that is considered a series circuit(no breaks all the wires are one making a whole piece).

Comment: It's not considered a circuit, at all. Circuits are an abstraction of electrodynamics for which the geometry of the connection between lumped elements doesn't matter. In this case the geometry does matter and circuit theory can't do anything to characterize the system and one has to actually understand the effects of induction on the geometry.

Comment: That's what I've thought initially, however, a wire could divide(split) the currents to $I$/$N$ of wires(assuming the wire's resistance is the same) at the equal voltage. The principle of series/parallel could be applied to a singular wire as well.

Comment: Your initial thought was better than your current thinking. Circuits don't describe geometry and are not meant to. You can, of course, introduce inductive  circuit elements in series with resistors and try to model the interaction between them with a coupled transformer model... but that's going to be a drag and it does not describe the physical situation all that well. In any case, if you are working with eddy currents and EMF, then the real question is usually how to reduce them as much as possible, for which you have to know that a comb is the correct solution and not what you have there.

Answer (score 1):

Reducing eddy current does not change property of conductor or circuit Eddy currents (also called Foucault currents) are circular electric currents induced within conductors by a changing magnetic field in the conductor, due to Faraday's law of induction. Eddy currents flow in closed loops within conductors, in planes perpendicular to the magnetic field. so it happens in any type of conductor providing its orientation should be perpendicular to magnetic field actually eddy currents are undesirable because they dissipate energy in form of heat energy so to reduce them we technically try to reduce the surface area as in above copper plate  example so the less area is available for eddy current and henceforth means less energy dissipation in form of heat

magnetic moment  of induced current(m) which opposes motion =IA where I is current and A is area so reducing area can solve the problem of energy loss and can reduce it

so we are not altering propery of conductor here as you can see